# AWS Quicksight folder permissions

Tags: amazon-quicksight

Can aws cli be used to grant a quicksight group (such as viewer or owner) to a quicksight folder? I can't seem to find the specific cli command.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this using the `update-folder-permissions` api call https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/quicksight/update-folder-permissions.html

It might help to first use the `list-folder-permissions` on existing folders to determine the correct structure for the `--grant-permissions` list

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:
aws quicksight update-folder-permissions 
--aws-account-id YOUR_AWS_ACCOUNT_ID 
--folder-id YOUR_FOLDER_ID 
--grant-permissions Principal=arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_NUMBER:root,Actions="quicksight:*",Permission=READ

In the v2 version (currently the latest), to correct the proper structure of permissions, you will need to use [describe-folder-permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/quicksight/describe-folder-permissions.html) api in place of list-folder-permissions